# Android - Intent problem

Tags: android, android-intent

i have remote service in which when particular time comes, i show a notification. in notification i add extra value (ex. k=0) and pass it to proper activity. so first time activity receives  correct value ( k=0). but when next time comes again in remoteservice i reset k=1 and add this extra value in notification. but this time activity receives only previous value (k=0) only not new value(k=1). Could some body see my code and correct me if i am wrong. Code in remote service.....

```
Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.tablet, text,System.currentTimeMillis());
    Intent intent = new Intent(RemoteService.this, SnoozeActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("k",c);       
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,intent, 0);        
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, getText(R.string.remote_service_label),text, contentIntent);
    myNM.notify(0, notification);
```

Code in receiver...

```
            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(extras !=null){
        int v = extras.getInt("k");
        Log.w("SnoozeActivity","k value : "+v);
    }
```

is it possible to reset putExtra value in intent...if so how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

you need to pass the unique number for 2nd argument for the getActivity method

this was identify the resultcode was different for same or different intent

```
  PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, unique_number,intent, 0);
```

same in the notify() method for notification

Answer (score 0):

try in your receiver

`int v = Integer.parseInt(extras.getString("k"));` instead